# ByPass validation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have used [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

To validate some input fields, but I need to bypass validation when the user click the cancel button(which preforms a posts back)

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Sp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("myButton").click(function () { 
    $("#mainform").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
    $("#mainform").submit(); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I tried this and the answer is even simpler.

```
$("myButton").click(function () { 
    $("#mainform").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
});
```

The other two lines prevented my cancel button's submit action from working, so I whittled it down to just this one line and now it works great, validating on submit but not on cancel.

This allows my cancel button to submit the form with its Spring Web Flow event id regardless of the valid state of the form.